# Passing column name with spaces through Zend Framework's select()

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a database table that has a column with a space in its name: `Audio book`s. I want to `select all rows where Audio books = 1`. I'm using [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework) to do this. My function looks like this:

```
 public function fetchAudio ()
 {
     $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select(array('Audio books' => 1));
     return $resultSet;
 }
```

The goal is to SELECT all rows WHERE "Audio books" = 1.

The site is returning this error:

> Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`books` = 1' at line 1)

How do I get this column work with that method?

Answer (score 0):

Having a space in your column name is a really, really bad idea. SQL will interpret a query like this: `SELECT your column` as `SELECT your AS column`.

You'll probably be able to get away with it using back ticks around your column name with spaces, but just take the space out of your column name!

Try this anyway - it's worth a shot:

```
$this->tableGateway->select(array('`Audio books`' => 1));
```

Comment: so I have following:

Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`books````` = 1' at line 1)


Sorry, it's important for me to leave that column name. I'm searching hard to pass through this...

Comment: Can you clarify the objective? Is it that `Audio books` should be a static column with value `1`? Or is a filter condition `WHERE Audio books = 1`?

Comment: Yes, exactly WHERE Audio books = 1

Answer (score 0):

You must simply get the adapter through tableGateway and pass the SQL query to it without any additional methods:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE `Audio books` = 1";
     $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->query($sql, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
     return $resultSet;
```